# Allow system to sleep even with audio stream running

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

For a bit of background info: I have a 2010 MacBook Pro 15 with OSX 10.10.2 installed.

I'm looking to make the laptop go to sleep even when a proccess that sets PreventUserIdleSystemSleep=1 is open. In this particular case, it as coreaudiod.

I was thinking of something similar to the Windows powercfg -requestsoverride for specific processes/drivers.

Comment: Do you need the process to keep running?

Comment: Mainly, yes. In my example, if I leave the Mac in the room on some youtube playlist before falling asleep, I don't want to have to close the process manually.

Comment: I can find a million ways to test if PreventUserIdleSystemSleep=1 is set but none whatsoever to override it - even https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html didn't give me a clue, but it may to someone smarter than me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a third party tool like Power Manager to make your Mac [sleep after a period of inactivity](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-04-20-how-to-make-your-mac-idle-sleep-after-different-times-on-different-days/).

[image: Power Manager - power off after inactivity]

Unlike OS X's Energy Saver, [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) can put your unused Mac to sleep even when an application or process has requested otherwise.

Disclaimer: I wrote Power Manager and can answer comments about how it works.

Comment: Awesome app - thanks for the disclaimer - this is exactly what I'll need to recommend for some clients.

Comment: So, the only sure way is to schedule when to enter sleep.
It isn't exactly what I am looking for, because I don't always know when I am supposed to fall asleep.

Comment: I will consider the answer if nothing simpler is available.

Comment: Power Manager can put your Mac to [sleep after periods of inactivity](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-04-14-how-to-make-your-mac-sleep-after-inactivity/) – no need to set pre-determined times.

Comment: I'll test it then when I have the time and get back to this.